# mysql SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 not working from command line or shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

Set foreign_key_checks=0 is working well from mysql prompt and I was able to delete records which is having foreign key constraints.

But from shell if I run the same command no error is showing but when I go to mysql and run delete command it shows foreign key error.
$(echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" | mysql --uuser --ppassword db) 
I have to run this from a shell script. 
Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: So, you are running the delete command as `.sql` script?

Comment: Not from .sql, from shell script, bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the `DELETE` command from script `.sql` file then you can try running the below command from shell/command line

```
{echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" ; cat delete_query.sql ; } | mysql
```

You can run this command in a shell script either using

```
RESULT=`mysql -u username -p password -D dbname 
    -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DELETE FROM mytable WHERE some_condition;"`
```

(OR) using a `HERETAG` like

```
RESULT=`/usr/bin/mysql -u username -p password<<SQL
use DB_Name
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE some_condition;
quit
SQL`
```

Comment: I have a series of command to execute from shell script, it has to run as a cron job. So I have to include same in shell script.

Comment: @user3717858, put all your SQL command in `.sql` file and then run it directly from shell script. that's way it's much better then running singly.

Comment: It not contains simple mysql commands, has variables and loops. I have to rewrite it to procedure. Will give a try if there is no other solution. Thank you.

Comment: Of course I will try this option. But I already written shell script which is quite long, only this command is not working, that is why I am thinking of getting some solution for the same.

Comment: @user3717858, check edited answer to see how to run the command in shell script.

Comment: @user3717858, Then it's time to accept the answer by clicking the check button under voting button. Also, make it a good habit to accept the answer that helped you; to show your respect towards other effort.

Comment: Oh..am very new to stackoverflow. I do ot know the functionalities. It is not about the habit. Thank you for the help :)